# Audio services in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, services, windows-services

In an attempt of blocking a viral service on my system (which was restarting my system automatically for every 30 seconds), I disabled all the services, and later enabled trustworthy services only.

(note: Hide all microsoft services didn't work blocking the auto restart so I disabled all services)

Now I have been succeeded in blocking automatic restart and I am able to access internet and all other necessary stuffs. Well, however system audio is mute(definitely because a necessary service is not running). Now I need a list of services that need to be started (set automatic) on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Windows 7 Service Configurations](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-configurations/)
- [Windows 7 Service Pack 1 Service Configurations](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/)

And, for future reference :)

- [Windows 8 Service Configurations](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-8-service-configurations/)

Comment: I am aware of this list, and actually the list is too huge to refer. I need to know (just) those service which are responsible for enabling audio!

Comment: moreover, when I clicked on hide all microsoft services and disabled the rest, system was still suffering auto-restart. That means, it might be a nagging (system default) service which is doing it or a viral service in the **name of windows service** doing this job. so list of microsoft windows 7 services won't really help.

Comment: You can always use the registry files for restoring default [Win7](http://www.blackviper.com/2009/10/03/windows-7-services-registry-files/) and [Win7 SP1](http://www.blackviper.com/2010/12/16/windows-7-service-pack-1-services-registry-files-2/) services settings. Apply, reboot and if that doesn't help, it must be the fault of some non-MS service or possibly even malware. For that you'd need to check your system thoroughly.